# Json_encode not capturing input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-4, json

I'm trying to use json_encode in a Laravel form to capture all the input of a form but currently it will capture some and ignore others. And when I say "ignore" I mean it is not collecting them and saving them to the database as I can see when I open it in the DB or when I try to call it somewhere else and only some of the inputs are there.

To be more specific json_encode will capture any of my normal inputs, inputs where the users directly enter a value, and my "other" inputs which are inputs that are added via JS by a push of a button. It ignores any input that has a set value, selects that have a selected option with a value, and inputs that are initially blank but have values inserted via JS.

Any advice or insight where I'm going wrong and/or how to correctly capture all the input in the form would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Form (or View) snippet:

An example of the kinds of input json_encode catches:
Normal Input:

```
 {{ Form::label('estimate_name', 'Estimate Name:')}}
    {{ Form::text('estimate_name') }}
```

"Other" Input:

```
<input name="description_1" class="description" placeholder="Other" />

<input name="cost_1" class="cost"/></td>
<input name="quantity_1" class="quantity" /></td>
<input name="amount"/></td>
```

And here is an example of the kind of input it ignores where "foo_a" and "bar_b" are filled via JS actions:

```
<input id="takeOut_C" value="2.50" class="take out"></input>
<input id="foo_a" class="standard"/>
<input id="bar_b" class="total"/>
```

And here is where I'm using json_encode in my controller:

```
$estimate_serialized    = json_encode(Input::except('_token', 'submit'));
$estimate = Estimate::create('estimate_serialized'=> $estimate_serialized,));
```

Thanks again for any help or advice! It is greatly appreciated!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to put `name` attributes in your `HTML`. When you have no `name` attributes, the data doesn't get `POSTed` via your `HTTP request`. Try adding `name` attributes like the following input tag:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname">
```

Comment: Thanks man, you answered my question perfectly. I'll be sure to keep this in mind for later.